# 2 pick events 2 colorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have 2 colorbars and I want both of them to have different pickevents
How can i do this?
my code atm is

```
    x_ax.set_picker(5)##colorbar set picker

def on_pick(event):
    artist = event.artist
    val = event.mouseevent.ydata
    xal = event.mouseevent.xdata
    if highlight == 1 :
        print 'hello'
        global highlight
        highlight = 0
        self.canvas.draw()
    if highlight == 0 :
        highlight = 2
        trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(self.ax.transAxes,self.ax.transData )
        rect = patches.Rectangle((0,1),width=5, height=5, transform=trans, color='yellow',alpha=0.5)
        self.ax.add_patch(rect)
        self.canvas.draw()
        rect.remove()


    else:
        self.canvas.draw()
        trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(self.ax.transAxes,self.ax.transData )
        rect = patches.Rectangle((0,10),width=25, height=25, transform=trans, color='yellow',alpha=0.5)
        self.ax.add_patch(rect)
        highlight = 1

        self.canvas.draw()
        rect.remove()


self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',on_pick)
```

I tried adding `x2_ax.setpicker(5)` and  `self.canvas.mpl.connect('pick_event', on_click)`
but it just seemed to do both of them when you clicked either colorbar

My on_pick just highlights a section on a graph

How can i add a seperate pick event for each colorbar???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting the pick event to the `canvas` and you only get one pick event per `canvas`.  You need to add code your `on_pick` that can tell which artist it is dealing with.  You can do this with closures, a slightly simpler/less elegant way is to simply add a `label` to your axes

```
x_ax.set_label('x')
y_ax.set_label('y')
```

and then in your `on_pick`

```
def on_pick(event):
    #some code here
    art = event.artist
    if isinstance(art, matplotlib.axes.Axes):
        # the artist is as axes
        if art.get_label() == 'x':
            # do one thing
            pass
        elif art.get_label() == 'y':
            # do another thing
            pass
```

You could do slightly better by making a `dict` keyed by the labels and with functions an the value, particularly if you end up with many labeled artists.